# Gauge Speedometer

Tags: javascript, ajax, highcharts, meter

Does anyone know if I can use the `High Charts` speed o meter with Ajax calls?  I was thinking in the following function putting the call in where I point out.  But I know sometimes this types of `graphs, charts, meters` don't like Ajax calls.

```
  // Add some life
function (chart) {
    setInterval(function () {
        var point = chart.series[0].points[0],
            newVal,
            inc = **Ajax call here**;

        newVal = point.y + inc;
        if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 20) {
            newVal = point.y - inc;
        }

        point.update(newVal);

    }, 3000);
```

In fact I really don't need an Ajax call within the function.  I just need an Ajax call to the server, check to see if it's '`squaking`' if it is use a Boolean set that to true and then use a `random number between say 1-20`, and if it's not just set the function to output 0;.

It's essentially a bandwidth meter so to speak, I'm just wondering if it's possible with this meter before I spend 5 hours on it for nothing if it's not possible.  Can anyone give suggestions?

Here is the meter in JSFiddle where I'm currently messing around with it.

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/gauge-speedometer/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly you can

```
setInterval(function () {
    var point = chart.series[0].points[0],
        newVal,
        inc = 0;

    $.get('squaking', function (data) {
        newVal = point.y + data.inc;
        if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 20) {
            newVal = point.y - data.inc;
        }

        point.update(newVal);
    });
}, 3000);
```

I'm assuming here that "**squaking**" is a server side function that returns a JSON result containing a value for **inc**. Once the data is returned, the chart is then updated.

Comment: Yeah you hit the nail on the head.  Do I have to use json ?  Or can I just have some values within a text file?  If I have to use json, do you happen to know where I could learn how to write a json file?  I know how to grab json data from a file but never really have written data into a file.  Thanks.

Comment: Absolutely not. You can use anything you like. I just used $.get returning JSON as an example but it all depends on what the server side function returns. "data" could be json, html, text, xml etc.

Comment: Cool...I actually don't need to return data.  I just need to make a call to the server to see that it's returning 4 and 200...then I can use any interger between 1 and 20...if not use zero showing that the server is down.  Essentially a bandwidth meter but not true data...thanks for the help!